# Is there a neutral expression that just means that the brake was pressed normally from the foot?

Tags: phrase-request

I think the sentence, "I pressed the brakes" has an undertone that the action was performed from hands while the sentence, "I stomped on the brakes" somewhat implies that massive force was applied.

Is there a neutral expression that just means that the break was pressed normally from the foot?

Comment: A brake is not a break. The 'undertone' that you perceive does not exist - you can press with the feet. I think, though, that 'tread' may be the verb that you seek.

Comment: Exact context might make a difference, but in general ***I braked*** is likely to imply ***...sharply / suddenly***. If you don't want that implication, just say ***I slowed down*** (or ***pulled up*** if you "braked to a stop")..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think the sentence, "I pressed the brakes" has an undertone that the action was performed from hands

There's no such implication. It's well understood that when driving a car, the brakes are normally applied with the foot.

You can also say

- I stepped on the brake.
- I applied the brakes.
- I braked the car.

If writing for an American audience I would avoid the word *tread* that was suggested in comments because it is very rare here.